# Questions:Implement an algorithm to determine if a string has all unique characters. What if you cannot use additional data structure

Tags: java, unicode, int, ascii

solution:

```
public boolean isUniqueChars2(String str) {
    if (str.length() > 256) return false;
    boolean[] char_set = new boolean[256];
    for (int i = 0; i< str.length(); i++) {
        int val = str.charAt(i);
        if (char_set[val]) {
            return false;
        }
        char_set[val] = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have some questions:

1. The codes is based on the premise that the given string is a ASCII string, what if it is a Unicode string? What's the difference between ASCII string and Unicode string?
2. int val=str.charAt(i) 
   I searched ASCII table, [image: ASCII table]

If the string is "@ABCD", what number will return?(which of the three"Dec, Hx, Oct" will be use?)

3. The str.charAt(i) should return a character (e.g. A), why declaring the data type as int can directly convert the character to the accordingly ASCII table's number?

Comment: ASCII has only 128 characters. You must have gotten 256 from one dozens of other character sets that have up to 256 characters.

Comment: Unicode has many nuances. The standard refers the the concept of a "grapheme," which could be what you are thinking of as "character". Some questions to ponder: Do you want to count 'a' with an acute accent ("\u00E1") the same as 'a' combined with an acute accent ("\u0061\u0301") and both different than 'a' without an accent ("\u0061")? If so, you have to normalize. Do you want to handle codepoints that require two Java `char`s to encode? Musical symbol eigth note  ("\uD834\uDD60") is different than Musical symbol sixteenth note  ("\uD834\uDD61").

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

To make your solution work for Unicode characters too, change these lines:

> ```
> if (str.length() > 256) return false;
> boolean[] char_set = new boolean[256];
> ```

To this instead:

```
if (str.length() > Character.MAX_VALUE + 1) return false;
boolean[] char_set = new boolean[Character.MAX_VALUE + 1];
```

---

> 2. int val=str.charAt(i) I searched ASCII table. If the string is "@ABCD", what number will return? (which of the three "Dec, Hx, Oct" will be use?)

You could just run the code and see for yourself.
`"@ABCD".charAt(0)` returns `@` of type `char`.
Converted to `int` that's 64 as per the ASCII table.

Dec, Hx, Oct are all just translations of the same thing.
Just like "book" in Spanish will be "libro",
63 in hexadecimal will be `0x3f`.

> 3. The str.charAt(i) should return a character (e.g. A), why declaring the data type as int can directly convert the character to the accordingly ASCII table's number?

I guess this is how `char` is defined in the language itself,
but I can't find the authoritative reference.

Answer (score 0):

> The str.charAt(i) should return a character (e.g. A), why declaring the data type as int can directly convert the character to the accordingly ASCII table's number?

When you write `int i = str.charAt(...)`, the Java language spec calls that *Widening Primitive Conversion*.  You are allowed to do it because `int` and `char` are both integer-like numeric types, and every legal char value is also a legal int value.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#25214

As for why ASCII?  It's because Unicode was deliberately designed for compatibility with the US-ASCII character set.  For every character in ASCII, it's Unicode encoding has the same numeric value as its ASCII encoding.

---

which of the three"Dec, Hx, Oct" will be use?

The numbers in the Dec, Hx, and Oct columns are just the same number represented with different place-value bases.  Take the letter 'A' for example.  When you express the numeric code for 'A' in decimal, it's "65".  The same number expressed in base 16 is "41", and in base 8 it's "101".  The table gives the codes in all three bases because all three are commonly used in computer programs, and in the documentation of computer hardware and software.

Base 8 and base 16 are commonly used because all modern computers represent numbers in base 2, and it's trivially easy to convert between base 2 and base 8 or base 16.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal