# implement an algorithm to determine if a string has all unique characters (characters greater than U+FFFF)

Tags: java, string, unicode

I was practicing example interview questions and one of them was:
"implement an algorithm to determine if a string has all unique characters".

It's easy when we assume that is ASCII/ANSI.
[implement-an-algorithm-to-determine-if-a-string-has-all-unique-charact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326695/questionsimplement-an-algorithm-to-determine-if-a-string-has-all-unique-charact)

But my question is: how should that be solved if let's say string can contain e.g. hieroglyphic symbols or whatever (code points are greater than U+FFFF... ?).

So if I understood it correctly I can easily think of solution if given string contains characters that belong to the set of characters from U+0000 to U+FFFF - they can be converted into 16-bit char, but what if I encounter a character whose code points are greater than U+FFFF... ?

> Characters whose code points are greater than U+FFFF are called supplementary characters. The Java platform uses the UTF-16 representation in char arrays and in the String and StringBuffer classes. In this representation, supplementary characters are represented as a pair of char values, the first from the high-surrogates range, (\uD800-\uDBFF), the second from the low-surrogates range (\uDC00-\uDFFF)

But I have no idea how to solve this puzzle in that case, how do I handle those surrogate pairs ?

Thanks!

Comment: Characters or code points? That's already something completely different. Unicode is currently limited to 17*2^16 code points so you can easily store them in an integer - depending on your used encoding you'll have to worry about surrogates, but you've figured that one out already. If it's really about *characters* Knuth help your soul, because I don't even want to think about all the complexities of that (I can't even say it's impossible if you know the language for which you should check - for all I know there might be some some theoretical possibility).

Comment: Which version of Java?

Comment: You can use code points instead.

Comment: Whether code points or ASCII characters, this is going to reduce to identifying duplicate _integers_ from a particular range.  The stringiness doesn't matter.

Comment: @Peter Characters and code points are two totally different things.

Comment: @Louis Only true if you're talking about code points. If we want to figure out *characters* it's vastly more complex: There are e.g. several ways to encode "è".

Comment: @Voo We can probably safely assume that the OP means code points. Otherwise there's not much to answer except what you already said. ("It's really, really hard.")

Comment: @Radiodef Probably. Although if I were interviewing someone for a position involving lots of text manipulation this would actually make a great question: I'd expect the candidate to explain the difference between characters and code points and why doing it for the former is so hard. And then as an afterthought let them solve the rather trivial puzzle with code points.

Comment: I might be mixing things up, but I'm thinking -> I have string that theoretically contains a character whose code point is grater than U+FFFF -> I can convert it into char array and I assume I would get surrogate pair (pair of char values), right? -> Then I try to convert that array into int array and I wonder if surrogate pair can be easliy converted to int ? Or do i need to do something more complex (after all it is a pair of char values!)? I'm really confused.

Comment: @Voo: to avoid confusion, you may want to use _graphemes_ or _user-perceived characters_ for your _characters_, to avoid confusion with _codepoints_, which are also known as _programmer-perceived characters_, to avoid confusion with Java `char`s (_code-units_), or with C's multi-byte characters and wide characters. The term _character_ is _really_ overloaded.

Comment: @ninjalj Fair enough, I wanted to avoid confusion by introducing "grapheme", but that might add to more confusion than avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 8 has a [`CharSequence#codePoints` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints--) that produces an `IntStream` of the Unicode codepoints in a string.  From there it just becomes a matter of writing code to test uniqueness of elements in the `IntStream`.

If you're still in Java 7 or below, there are codepoint-based methods in there that can be used to solve this as well, but they much more complex to use.  You'd have to loop over the `char`s of the string and examine each one's value to tell whether you're dealing with surrogate pairs or not.  Something like (thoroughly untested):

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    int codepoint = str.codePointAt(i++);
    if (Character.isHighSurrogate(str.charAt(i))) {
        // This will fail if the UTF-16 representation of 
        // this string is wrong (e.g., high surrogate `char` 
        // at the end of the string's `char[]`).
        i += 1;
    }
    // do stuff with codepoint...
}
```

Comment: If you are using Java 8, it’s not even “a matter of writing code to test uniqueness of elements in the `IntStream`”, it’s just as simple as `string.codePoints().distinct().count()==string.codePoints().count()`